# Issues while sending Array or int via i2c from Arduino to STM32

Tags: c, arduino, embedded, stm32, i2c

I've to establish a connection between an Arduino and a STM32 (programming with C and HAL). the Arduino is used in Slave Mode, while the STM32 is used in Master Mode.
At this state, I can easily perform these transmission :

- integer from STM32 to Arduino;
- integer array from STM32 to Arduino;
- uint8_t array (a "string") from STM32 to Arduino;
- String from Arduino to STM32;
  Exchanges are checked by displaying what's received on terminal with uart.

So the transmission from STM32 to Arduino work as expected. But I've some difficulties with reception. Even for receiving a String from Arduino, I had to do this with the instruction `Wire.write(Message.c_string());` on my Arduino. But if I try to receive an integer, nothing happend on the STM32 terminal. And if I try to receive an integer array, I see on my terminal N empty characters, and then the cursor (N is the size of the array).
Thus I'm sure I'm receiving something... But I can't identify if :

1. I receive wrong datas
2. I don't display it properly

Do someone have any idea of what's causing this behavior ? You can find my code bellow.

```
    /* On STM32. I'm just sharing the main function to avoid to flood the topic. Please be assured that all the other stuff, as UART or I2C configuration, is done properly*/
    
    int main(void)
    {
        HAL_StatusTypeDef retour_i2c;
    
        uint8_t message_envoye[] = "Hello World !!";
        uint8_t entier_envoye = 32;
        uint8_t tableau_envoye[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    
        uint8_t message_recu[10];
        uint8_t entier_recu;
        uint8_t tableau_recu[4]; // My Arduino is sending an array of 4 integers
    
      HAL_Init();
      SystemClock_Config();
      MX_GPIO_Init();
      MX_USART2_UART_Init();
      MX_I2C1_Init();
    
      I2C_Verif_Addresses();
    
      while (1)
      {
          // Transmition part is OK
          retour_i2c = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, (uint16_t)(I2C_SLAVE_ADDR << 1), tableau_envoye, sizeof(tableau_envoye), 1000);
          if(retour_i2c != HAL_OK){
              I2C_Error_Handler(&hi2c1);
          }
          else{
              HAL_Delay(1000);
              HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin);
          }
    
    
          // Reception part is not OK
          // retour_i2c = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, (uint16_t)(I2C_SLAVE_ADDR << 1), message_recu, sizeof(message_recu), 1000); // "strings" are working
          retour_i2c = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, (uint16_t)(I2C_SLAVE_ADDR << 1), tableau_recu, sizeof(tableau_recu), 1000); // Receiving an array cause invisible characters to be printed
          // retour_i2c = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, (uint16_t)(I2C_SLAVE_ADDR << 1), entier_recu, sizeof(entier_recu), 1000);
          if(retour_i2c != HAL_OK){
              I2C_Error_Handler(&hi2c1);
          }
          else{
              HAL_Delay(1000);
              HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin);
              HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, tableau_recu, sizeof(tableau_recu), 10);
          }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sending binary data via UART will not display a readable result in a terminal program.

If the values correspond to the encoding of printable characters you will see something, but not the values of a number, e.g. a binary value of `0x31 = 49` will be printed as `1`.

You could use `sprintf` to convert the numbers to a string representation or write your own conversion function. Or use a program that can display your binary data as a hexdump to check the values.

**Example:**

```
   for(uint_8 i = 0; i < sizeof(tableau_recu); i++)
   {
      uint8_t buf[32];
      int n = sprintf((char*)buf, "%d\n", (int)tableau_recu[i]);
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint16)buf, n, 10);
   }
```